# Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Class::__construct(), 0 passed in and at least 1 expected in PHP7.1

Tags: php, php-7.1

I am learning PHP but I encountered a new problem. I would appreciate if you help.

My code:

```
$idTrack = (new Track_Obj)->getIdtCommon($a,$b);
```

---

```
Class Track_Obj{
function __construct( $idtakip, $env = false ) {...}

function getIdtCommon( $idref, $idstudent, $env = false) {...}
}
```

Error:

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Track_Obj::__construct(), 0  passed in and at least 1 expected in  PHP7.1

Comment: $a cant be empty

Comment: $idtakip must be passed when creating an object of class Track_Obj

Comment: also  , $a not empty, it is example value, you think like $a=1.

Comment: @ jakub wrona you can say this like example :$idTrack = (new Track_Obj($idtakip))->getIdtCommon($a,$b);  ?   But I dont use it $idtakip

Comment: To explain, `(new Track_Obj)` or more practically `new Track_Obj()` calls the `Track_Obj` constructor. That constructor has one required argument (`$idtakip`) and one optional (`$env`). You need to provide at least one argument for `$idtakip`, eg `new Track_Obj($something)`. I do not recommend omitting the parentheses when creating class instances as it just makes code confusing to read, ie `new Something;` ❌ vs `new Something();` ✔️

Comment: @Phil You should turn this into an answer

Comment: @FrankerZ this question doesn't need an answer. The error message explains **exactly** what is wrong. If OP needs more information, there's [plenty of duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+Uncaught+ArgumentCountError) around

Comment: thank you for answer and explanation @Phil

Answer (score 0):

Solve:

New code:

```
    $idTrack = (new Track_Obj($idtakip))->getIdtCommon($a,$b);
 or
    $class=new Track_Obj($idtakip);
    $idTrack = $class->getIdtCommon($a,$b);
```

Thank you for help and explanation @Phil